# How to get woocomerce attributes thumbnail in PHP?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, terms

I'm trying to get all atribute names and images(thumbnails?) to print them , I've managed to get their names , but not the url of the image I can't find it . To add an image to woocommerce attributes I used the [Variation swatches extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-variation-swatches/) .

Here is how I get the names of the attributes

```
$attributes = get_terms("pa_couleurs");
foreach ($attributes as $attribute){
    Print  $attribute->name;
}
```

Ideally , I want to get the image URL so I can put them inside an html tag .

Answer (score 1):

There is a lovely function [`get_term_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/), which you can use to get the any `WP_Term` object archive page URL.

Just add this inside your `foreach` loop:

```php
$url = get_term_link( $attribute );
```

---

**Edit**

Since you need to retrieve a certain meta value for each attribute, try fetching them all and var_dumping them, to see what is it exactly that you need.

For example:

```php
/** @var \WP_Term[] $attributes */
$attributes = get_terms( 'pa_couleurs' );

foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
    echo  $attribute->name;

    // Get all attribute meta data
    $meta = get_term_meta( $attribute->term_id );

    // Dump it out on the page. Remove after you find the key(s) you need
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $meta );
    echo '</pre>';

    // After finding the exact meta key that holds the info you need, edit this
    $images = (array) get_term_meta( $attribute->term_id, 'change_this', true );

    // This will probably hold the array of attachment IDs, so you'll need to get the URL's from that
    foreach ( $images as $image_id ) {

        // Get image src from ID
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'thumbnail' );

        // If src is found
        if ( $src ) {
            echo '<img src="' . $src . '" alt="Attribute Image">';

        } // If not
        else {
            echo 'No image src for the image ID ' . $image_id . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it does return a link (https://*****.**/?taxonomy=pa_colors&term=yellow) but not what I actually want , I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough , but I want the image url assigned to the atribute , each atribute has an unique image .

Comment: @Haza Please see updated answer.